# How to return custom catch error in Observable Http?

Tags: angular

I have an observable function, that does request:

```
public send(): Observable<ISms[]> {

    if (this.usedAttempts < this.maxAttempts) {
      return; // Here return custom error
    }
}
```

I take this observable like as:

```
this.sms.send().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I need to check if user can send Sms if yes, send, otherwise return error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `throw()` operator:

```
if (this.usedAttempts < this.maxAttempts) {
    return Observable.throw('error description');
}
```

Don't forget to import it:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Here is what [the docs say](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw):

> Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and
>   immediately emits an error notification.

Comment: Is it correct way, or better created separated method that check?

Comment: @Daniel, that's subjective, you probably could create a separate method which would be more expressive, like `if (this.sms.canSend()) { this.sms.send() }`. But if the server also performs some validation and may return the same error, then I would leave the check inside the `send` method

Answer (score 2):

```
public send(): Observable<ISms[]> {

    if (this.usedAttempts < this.maxAttempts) {
      return Observable.throw(customError)
    }
}
```